# Jacoco: Measure coverage only over Public Methods

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Is there any way of doing this? I can see that jacoco counts the amount of methods, but I don't know if it can distinguish the accessibility.

I am using jacoco-maven-plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: I also use the jacoco maven plugin, and I do not believe there is a way to only have code coverage for public methods.  It allows exclusions at the class level only.  Why would you want code coverage only for public methods?

Comment: That what I thought. I have been told that due to the fact this is going to be a public project they want to ensure certain coverage regarding public methods, but I am not quite sure if this it is valid acceptance criteria. Thanks @jrahhali